time data jan 5 2017 doesn't match format in jupyter notebook
import pandas as pd
dates=['2017-01-05','Jan 5,2017','20170105']
pd.to_datetime(dates)

I am expecting the date would be
2017-01-5(YY/mm/dd).But I found Value error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\dev\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 1099, in to_datetime
    result = convert_listlike(argc, format)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\dev\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 433, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    return _array_strptime_with_fallback(arg, name, utc, format, exact, errors)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\dev\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 467, in _array_strptime_with_fallback
    result, tz_out = array_strptime(arg, fmt, exact=exact, errors=errors, utc=utc)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "strptime.pyx", line 501, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
  File "strptime.pyx", line 451, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
  File "strptime.pyx", line 583, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime._parse_with_format
ValueError: time data "Jan 5,2017" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d", at position 1. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

Please give me a solution. Please tell me the right way to do it. I want the date would be same.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The error you get clearly tells you what to do.  Your last line should be pd.to_datetime(dates, format='mixed'). Please in the future post the entire error. There is the reason for it being a guideline (see below). Most times as a result you'll see your issue while putting together the post. Please read How do I ask a good question? before posting further as it is a good guide. Under 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem' it clearly states: 'Include any error messages'. See about 'fenced code blocks' ...

 here for pasting in error messages as code text, which is also an expectation spelled out in that guide

Also see here and here and here and here and here.

Also, that guide stresses 'Search, and Research' before posting a new post. However, you will have a hard time if you don't use the correct terms. You specified Pandas in your tag but not Python. Jupyter is irrelevant and should not be in your title. You can run a lot of languages in Jupyter, Python being just one. If you ran this code in a Python console or as a Python script you call from the command line, both the more traditional ways to use Python code, then you'd have the same issue. Therefore, Jupyter is not to blame and using that as a term won't help in your search.
